# How to get data from ngrx/store from route parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, ngrx

How to get particular product details from store to the other page while routing? I've tried to achieve this, but not able to sort out how to dispatch event for store from other route! See the following files for ref.

Here is my **product store** file:

```
import { Action, ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import {Product} from "../product.model/product.model";
export const productStore: ActionReducer<Product[]> = (status: Product[] = [], action: Action) => {
    switch(action.type){
         case 'SET_LIST' : status = action.payload;
                           return status;
      case 'GET_PRODUCT' : return status;
                 default : return status;
    }
}
```

Here is my **product page** where i've used ngrx/store:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from "../../product.model/product.model";
import {AppService} from "../../app.service/app.service";
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'product-pg',
  template: `
    Product List Goes Here:
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor = 'let product of $productList | async'>
        {{product.name}} - 
        <a [routerLink] = "['/product-details', product.id]">Edit</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class ProductPageComponent implements OnInit{
   private $productList: Observable<Product[]>;

   constructor(private _service: AppService, private _store: Store<Product[]>){}

   ngOnInit(){
     this.$productList = this._store.select('productList');
     this._service.setProductList()
   }
}
```

And here I wanted to get single product details - **product details page**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Product} from "../../product.model/product.model";
@Component({
  selector: 'product-details-page',
  template: `
    Product Details Page Goes Here...
    {{selectedProduct$ | async}}
  `
})
export class ProductDetailsPageComponent implements OnInit{
   private selectedProduct$:Observable<Product>;

   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _store :Store<Product>){}

   ngOnInit(){
     this.route.params.subscribe((param) => {
       console.log(param["id"])
       //Can't figure-out how to achieve this OR get store help here???
       this.selectedProduct$ = this._store.dispatch({type: 'GET_PRODUCT', payload: param["id"]});
     })
   }
}
```

Here I'm not able to get the single product details from store with the help of route parameter. How to achieve this, please help me?

Comment: `dispatch` does not return an observable. To retrieve state from the store, you need to `select` it - as in the `ProductPageComponent`. Even if you need to dispatch an action to load the details into the store, you will still need the `select`.

Comment: Thanks @cartant, It means wherever I needed store data OR slice of data, I need to right _store.select(...) statement in that component!!!